# Dropping multiple columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to drop multiple columns in oracle 10g using a single query ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm#i2124702

Answer (score 24):

How about this?

> ## Physical Delete
>
> To physically drop a column you can use one of the following syntaxes,
>   depending on whether you wish to drop a single or multiple columns.
>
> **ALTER TABLE** table_name DROP COLUMN column_name; **--drop SINGLE column**
>
> **ALTER TABLE** table_name DROP (column_name1, column_name2);   **--drop MANY columns**

[Source](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/dropping-columns)

```
alter table
       table_name
    drop
       (col_name1, col_name2);  -- drop MANY columns
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do it.

**1. You can mark a column as unused (logical delete)**

**(for single column)** -- Alter table table_name set unused (column_name);
**(for multiple column)**-- Alter table table_name set unused (column_name1, column_name2);

**2. or delete it completely (physical delete).**

**(for single column)**  -- Alter table table_name drop column column_name;
**(for multiple column)** -- Alter table table_name drop (column_name1, column_name2);